# Undefined ' this.props.navigation.state.props.p' navigation react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I have read all the other topics about this issue, but no one is the solution to my problem.

I don't know why, but I can't pass props to react-navigation when I try to navigate, I always get this error:

> "Undefined ' this.props.navigation.state.props.p'"

There is my code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBeFuR40n7vp1XU9edL8PeOFq3UafKQ314",
    authDomain: "anylibrary-961e1.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://anylibrary-961e1.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "anylibrary-961e1",
    storageBucket: "anylibrary-961e1.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "482573837189"
};

export default class Loading extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    componentWillMount() {
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
            if (user) {
                navigate('UserArea', {p: 'Profile'});
            } else {
                navigate('MainPage');
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Loading...</Text>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
})
```

And:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Alert} from 'react-native';
import Profile from './Profile';
import Notifications from './Notifications';
import Search from './Search';
import Home from './Home';
import Tabbar from 'react-native-tabbar-bottom'
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBeFuR40n7vp1XU9edL8PeOFq3UafKQ314",
    authDomain: "anylibrary-961e1.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://anylibrary-961e1.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "anylibrary-961e1",
    storageBucket: "anylibrary-961e1.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "482573837189"
};


export default class UserArea extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            page: this.props.navigation.state.props.p,
            name: '',
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
             this.state.name = user.displayName;
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {this.state.page === "Home" && <Home navigation={this.props.navigation}>Home</Home>}
                {this.state.page === "Profile" && <Profile navigation={this.props.navigation}>Profile</Profile>}
                {this.state.page === "Notifications" &&   <Notifications navigation={this.props.navigation}>Notifications</Notifications>}
                {this.state.page === "Search" && <Search navigation={this.props.navigation}>Search</Search>}

                <Tabbar
                    stateFunc={(tab) => {
                        this.setState({page: tab.page})
                        //this.props.navigation.setParams({tabTitle: tab.title})
                    }}
                    activePage={this.state.page}
                    tabbarBgColor='#00619A'
                    iconColor='#99c2ff'
                    tabs={[
                        {
                            page: "Home",
                            icon: "home",
                            iconText: "Home"
                        },
                        {
                            page: "Profile",
                            icon: "person",
                            iconText: "Profile"
                        },
                        {
                            page: "Notifications",
                            icon: "notifications",
                            badgeNumber: 0,
                            iconText: "Notifications"
                        },
                        {
                            page: "Search",
                            icon: "search",
                            iconText: "Search"
                        },
                    ]}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

Basically i send it like that:

```
navigate('UserArea', {p: 'Profile'});
```

and try to acces it like that:

```
page: this.props.navigation.state.props.p,
```

Anyone?

Where is the problem?

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe an element of your chain is null

Comment: Everything works fine, nothing seems to be null.
If i don't want to pass props, and i put like "page: 'Profile'" directly, everything works fine...

Comment: did you try removing the this from the constructor? `page: props.navigation.state.props.p,`

Answer (score 2):

from the documentation this looks like the correct way to get the route params

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.p
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

Comment: Is it 'p' some reserved word? Or? I changed it to 'mypage' and it works fine now... but i still not understand why it doesn't work before...

Comment: it's not a reserved word, maybe you had some other errors in your code :)

Answer (score 2):

**old method is**

this.props.navigation.state.params

**new method is**

this.props.route.params

im using rn version 0.62,
react navigation version -5

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 page: this.props.navigation.state.p
```

i advise you to use **getParam** - Get a specific param value with a **fallback**

```
const name = this.props.navigation.getParam('name', 'Peter');
```

if name or param are undefined, set the fallback to Peter.

Comment: I tryed all the possible way to get the params, from the documentation and other topis about this error.
Like i said above, solved by changing the name of the prop, no sense but works fine
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

If using react-navigation v5, use

```
const data = route.params?.someParam ?? 'defaultValue';
```